# jQuery .on() is giving me the wrong "this"

Tags: jquery, event-handling, targeting

Probably a slap-my-forehead solution, but:

```
<div id="foo">
   <!-- this will all be replaced periodically via AJAX -->
   <p id="bar_1">click me</p>
   <p id="bar_2">click me</p>
   <p id="bar_3">click me</p>
   <!-- end AJAXed section -->
</div>

$('#foo').on(click,'p',function(){
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
   //returns "foo"
});
```

Clicking any `p` alerts "foo". How do I return "bar_*n*", the id of the `p` that was clicked?

I'm targeting the outer `div` because it's reliable and not going to be replaced via AJAX.  Within the .on() method, I'm targeting (subtargeting?) the inner `p` because that's what I really want to bind the click handler to.  All the p's will be replaced periodically, and their bindings lost, therefore, I can't simply say `$('p').on(click...)`. Can I?

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xNnp2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add quote here `click`  like - `'click'` and every thing will be fine then, fiddle already submitted by @Arun.

Try this -

```
$('#foo').on('click','p',function(){
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
   //returns "foo"
});
```

Comment: That absolutely does work.  [head slap!]  Unfortunately, in my more complex real world code, I can't seem to make the `$(this)` call work.   I'll see if I can more accurately reproduce the problem next time...  Thank you.

Comment: If you care to take a look... I was able to reproduce my actual problem in pseudo code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guMjh)  I'm only getting "foo" on the alerts.

Comment: @anthony: `$('#foo').on('click','p', ...` not `$('#foo').on('click',$p, ...`

Comment: @anthony you applied `on` method on `foo` id so it is throwing this

Comment: @anthony with what Kabie suggested will prompt bar_1 this time

Comment: @anthony sorry my bad I edit the code and its giving me this..what Kabie suggested is good .. :)

Comment: @Kabie Thank you, that worked! My subtarget (that's what I'll call it) shouldn't have been the jQuery object `$('p')`, it should have been the selector string `p`!

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

Replace

```
$('#foo').on('click','p',function(){
```

with

```
$('#foo p').on('click',function(){
```

(as mentioned before, you need quotes around click).

OR, replace

```
alert($(this).attr('id'));
```

with

```
alert($(event.target).attr('id'));
```

I can't guarantee the first method will play nice with the AJAX loads, but I believe the second method should work just fine.